# Largest Infinitesimal Game

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

In combinatorial game theory, you can have infinitesimal games like up={0|*}={0|{0|0}}, and if you are allowed to use expressions that involve themselves as an option, like Off={|Off}, then you can find the smallest positive game: Tiny={0|{0|Off}} in the sense that there is no game that is less than Tiny but greater than 0.

What I want to know is: Is there a game which is in that sense the largest infinitesimal? In other words, does there exist a (infinitesimal) game G such that there is no other game H greater than G but less than all games with a real number value?

Note: There has been some confusion in the answers on what type of combinatorial games I am asking about. I want to know about the largest infinitesimal game out of all combinatorial games, including loopy and transfinite games.

Answer (score 5):

The original question brings up **tiny**, so the context is that of loopy games. If we restrict ourselves to *finite* loopy games, rather than the transfinite games Ted mentions in their answer, then the answer is "yes".

In that context, **over**={0|**over**} is the largest positive infinitesimal, being the infimum of the numbers of the form $1/2^n$ for integers $n$. Note: **over** + **over** = **over**, saving us from the "$G+G>G$" worry that Ted brought up.

**over** is also the supremum of numbers of the form $n\cdot\uparrow$, which answered the revised question "Is there a game $G$ such that for any infinitesimal $H$ there is an $n$ such that $H<nG$?" if you restricted things to the finite loopfree games.

Siegel's "Combinatorial Game Theory" is a great source for all of the above.

Answer (score 1):

There is no largest infinitesimal game, because if $G$ is a positive infinitesimal game, then 
$G+G$ is larger, but still infinitesimal.

However, in Chapter 16 of ONAG, in the section "The Gamut Revealed", we learn that the "largest infinitesimal games" are {$\alpha\, |\, \mathbb{R}^+ || \, \mathbb{R}^+\}$ where $\alpha$ is an ordinal.  I believe this means that any infinitesimal game is smaller than some game of this form, for some choice of ordinal $\alpha$.

Comment: Ah, right. Ok, revising the question a little: Is there a game G such that every infinitesimal game H is O(G)? In other words, is there a game G such that for any H there is an n such that H<nG?

Comment: Based on Ted's answer, no. Any infinitesimal game will be less than some $C(\alpha) = \lbrace \alpha \, |\, \mathbb{R}^+ \, || \, \mathbb{R}^+ \rbrace$. I'm not sure whether $n \cdot C(\alpha) = C(n \alpha)$, but we know that $n \cdot C(\alpha) \le C(\alpha_n)$ for some $\alpha_n$, so if we let $\beta = \bigcup \alpha_n$, we have $n \cdot C(\alpha) \le C(\beta)$ for all $n$. For the same reason, any set of infinitesimal games will be beaten by some infinitesimal game; you need a proper class to be cofinal in infinitesimal games.

Comment: Wait, if you used {On|R+||R+}, where On={On|}, would that work? It is bigger than any game {a|R+||R+}.

Comment: @Thomas Loopy transfinite games are not often studied, but that's an interesting idea... As an aside, I edited my answer to have the answer for finite loopy games.